# Classify data using ten fold cross validation in weka

Tags: weka

I am trying to learn Weka.I am using a data set which has three classes of activity. I am trying to build a classifier, use ten-fold cross validation  and tabulate the accuracy. However i cant tell which data belongs to which class. How do i proceed? I am not sure how to upload the data set here.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get results using a k-fold cross validation, your data points must have class labels. For instance, if I give you a set of data and ask you to classify them into three classes but I do not know the classes of the data points, when you classify them and return them back to me, how do I calculate your classification accuracy?